# Iptables forward all traffic to a specified port and IP address, to another device

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 4433 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:443
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.1 --dport 4433 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.2.15

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

where ip address 10.0.2.15 is your iptables computer

Tried on ubuntu 20.4

telnet 10.0.2.15 4433
Trying 10.0.2.15...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

telnet localhost 4433
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: What does a tcpdump show?

Comment: No traffic on TCP Dump

Comment: This test will not work from the host, it has to be run from a 3rd system. else use nat/OUTPUT

Comment: Thanks for your response